# How do I keep asking the user to input the valid characters?

Tags: python

I am writing a program called hangman.py. In my program the user cannot input "?' or whitespace in my input. 
For example, the user cannot enter: '?xx?xx?' or 'How do I do this'. But the user can input something like 'ldkdjgg' or 'stop-go'. 
If the user enter something like '?xxxxx?' or 'How do I do this' I have to keep asking the user "Please enter a word to be guessed that does not contain ? or white space:". 
My question is how do I print "Please enter a word to be guessed that does not contain ? or white space:" until the user stop entering '?' or whitespace in the input.

This is my idea but I am having trouble printing out "Please enter a word to be guessed that does not contain ? or white space:" if i enter a '?' or whitespace in my input

```
print("Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: ",end='')
while True:
  try:
      secret_word=input()
  except '?' or 'print()'
      print("Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: ",end='')
      continue
  else:
      break
```

Comment: So any input that contains even a single space or '?' should be rejected?

Comment: Yes. If i have a '?' or whitespace in my input I have to print("Please enter a word to be guessed that does not contain ? or white space:). But I can't print that statement if i enter a '?' or whitespace.

Comment: You allow punctuation; do you care about digits or other whitespace characters? You can reject anything not in `set(string.lowercase)` for free.

Comment: I am allow to use / - and other but not white space and question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `set("? ")` intersects with  `secret_word`, if it does the user entered at least one space or ?:

```
while True:
    secret_word = input("Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: ")
    if not set("? ").intersection(secret_word):
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

Demo:

```
Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: ?
Invalid input
Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: foo bar
Invalid input
Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: foo
```

Or use str.translate and compare the lengths after removing any spaces and ?:

```
tbl = str.maketrans({ord("?"):"",ord(" "):""})
while True:
    secret_word = input("Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: ")
    if len(secret_word.translate(tbl)) == len(secret_word):
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

`secret_word.translate(tbl)` will remove any spaces or `?` so if the length is the same after translating we know the user did not enter any, if it is different then we know they have. You can add as many bad characters as you want to the `tbl` dict using the `ord` as the key and an empty string as the value.

Comment: How do keep asking the user until the user has enter the valid input?

Comment: @stephenblack, this will keep asking until the user enter correct  data

Comment: Sorry! your right. I right. but If I change print("Invalid input) to print("Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: ") how come it displace two of ("Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: ") statements?

Comment: I wanted to change  print("Invalid input) to print("Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: ") and the output is one  print("Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: ") statement

Comment: @stephenblack, because we are already  displaying that message with input, the print invalid input is there to tell the user that they made an error, if the user enters bad input then the input message will be displayed again, there is no need for a print

Comment: No worries, there are more basic ways to do what you want but translate is very efficient and worth learning

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more readable solution:

```
user_input = raw_input("Please enter a string that doesn't contain spaces or '?':")

while " " in input or "?" in input:
    user_input = raw_input("Please enter a string that doesn't contain spaces or '?':")
```

Comment: i tried ur method but I think it just keep printing("Please enter a string that doesn't contain spaces or '?':") nonstop.

Comment: @stephenblack Yes. It will keep printing that until a valid string is input.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
bad_strings = [' ', '?']
secret_word = ' '

while any([s in secret_word for s in bad_strings]):
    secret_word = input("Enter a word that doesn't contain '?' or spaces: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
secret_word = " "
while set(secret_word) & set("? "):
    secret_word = input("Please enter a word to be guessedthat does not contain ? or white space: ")
```